# Save JTextPane superscript text as RTF

Tags: java, swing, save, rtf, jtextpane

How to save `JTextPane` superscript text as RTF?

I am trying to create WordPad like text editor. I used `RTFEditorKit`. I could add superscript using below code. (ex: X to the power 2)

```
public void setSuperscript() {
   EditorKit editorKit = this.getEditorKit();
   MutableAttributeSet att = ((StyledEditorKit) editorKit).getInputAttributes();
   StyleConstants.setSuperscript(att, !StyleConstants.isSuperscript(att));
   super.setCharacterAttributes(att, false);
}
```

And I saved the document as below.

```
public void save(String fileName) {
     BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream(fileName));
   try {
     StyledDocument doc = this.getStyledDocument();
     OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     this.getEditorKit().write(out, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
     out.close();
   }
}
```

It saved successfully. But when I open it using WordPad or Microsoft Word superscript formatting is missing.

Using AdvancedEditorKit I got this working.

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
AdvancedRTFDocument document = new AdvancedRTFDocument();
AdvancedRTFEditorKit editor = new AdvancedRTFEditorKit();
editor.write("test.rtf", document);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks Andre. I'll keep that mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternative `RTFEditorKit` http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Default one has limited functionality so many RTF formatting features are not supported.

Comment: I tried your AdvancedRTFEditorKit. but it didn't save anything. After saving document is blank.

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    AdvancedRTFEditorKit kit = new AdvancedRTFEditorKit();
    textPane.setEditorKit(kit);
    textPane.setDocument(new AdvancedRTFDocument());

    StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) textPane.getDocument();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.rtf");
    textPane.getEditorKit().write(out, doc, 0, doc.getLength());